# How to use to-many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

Lets say i've got 2 entities -- Athlete:with "fullname" attribute -- Eval:with "pullups" attribute -- i would want to set multiple evals for each name, but how to I tell it which name i would like to add the specific evals to?

My app is quite similar to the contacts app that comes preinstalled with iOS. The root view controller has my first entity, Athlete. it is a table view that displays all athletes. When you select an athlete, it shows all his/her info, and there is a button called show eval. Eval is my second entity. Athlete has a to-many relationship with Eval, meaning one athlete can have multiple evals, but evals can only have one athlete. I know how to add evals, but when I add them, they are just there, they don't have an owner, so regardless of which athlete I select, it just shows all the evals. How do I create an eval that correlates with the Athlete that was selected?

allevals.h

```
//the athlete selected pushes a tableviewcontroller with all evals, but I want it to only show evals for the athlete selected.
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s Evaluations",_athletesFullName];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    _managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *eval = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Eval" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:eval];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor =
    [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date_recorded"
                                ascending:NO
                                 selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil){
        //handle error
    }
    [self setEvalArray:mutableFetchResults];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The view controllers are as follows, all athletes tableview is root tableviewcontroller, then there is an add barbuttonitem which allows you to add an athlete. It reloads the view, then on the tableview you have your newly added athlete, you click on him, then it shows details, plus a button to look at his evals. From there, it is another tableview of evals with a barbuttonitem for adding. Problem is, I don't know how to tell the eval that was just added who its owner is.

Comment: When/where are you creating the eval? I guess you have the athlete at that time?

Comment: @Wain Will edit my question. Check it again please :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding a new eval:
create new eval entity and set the entity attributes as needed.
select the athlete that goes with the eval and call `addEval:` that will link the two together.

When trying to get all of the evals for an athlete use `athlete.evals` and it will just give you the eval entities attached to the athlete in question.

Comment: I set the "whoTook" relationship on the Eval, but how exactly do I sort with athlete.evals? Shouldn't it be like a NSPredicate?

Comment: `athlete.evals` will return an `NSSet` but you can use the `NSSet` method `- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors` to get an array sorted however you want. Keep in mind that `NSPredicate` is for filtering and `NSSortDescriptor` is for sorting.

Comment: which is preferred? why would I use NSPredicate vs NSSortDescriptor?

Comment: You use `NSSortDescriptor` to get a collection of evals _sorted_ by date while you use `NSPredicate` to get all evals from a _specific_ date, or _range_ of dates. You can also apply the same ideas to any other attributes of an entity. You _could_ use an `NSPredicate` to find all evals with a whoTook that matches the athlete you are looking at, but since there is a relationship that already has that info it is _much_ faster to grab the existing collection of evals attached to the athlete than it is to look at _all_ evals and check to see if the athlete is the right one.

Comment: The easiest way to see the difference in speed is to think about the evals as being on pieces of real paper. If those pieces of paper are already in stacks by athlete would you just look for the stack for the athlete you want or push all the evals into one big pile and go through looking for the ones with the correct athlete's name? Obviously a computer can do both things faster than a person, but the idea is the same; don't waste processor cycles and battery power when the works is already done.

Comment: Thank you for your continued support. I'm only 16 and just began ios programming. So how would I use the existing relationship with NSSortDescriptor?

Comment: `NSArray *sortedEvals = [someAthlete.evals sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: someSortDescriptor]];` Spend some time with the documentation most of it it is well written and will give you the answers you need most of the time. You can Also Google most any class name and get examples of how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Your fetch request has a sot order and an entity description, but you've missed the third item it can work with.

If you want to filter only the evals that apply to an athlete, you need to set a predicate on the fetchrequest.

Comment: When I add an eval do I need to do anything there to have its ownership set? Or will Core Data do it for me? E.g. in my eval code, I just insertNewEntity, at no point do I specify the Athlete in any way. Am I supposed to?

Comment: @user2674329, yes, you are supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

When the user selects to view the evals for an athlete you need to pass that athlete to the evals view controller. The view controller can now use it both in the filter predicate when it is getting the evals to display and to configure the link between the objects when a new eval is created.

---

```
newEval.whoTook = self.currentAthlete;
```

Comment: I understand that logic, what I don't understand is the following: Lets say i've got 2 entities -- Athlete:with "fullname" attribute -- Eval:with "pullups" attribute -- i would want to set multiple evals for each name, but how to I tell it which name i would like to add the specific evals to? Eval has the relationship whoTook (as in whos eval is it), and Athlete has evals relationship.